# Service Layer Architecture Design Confusion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, design-patterns

I am using MVC 3.  I am trying to get my head around the services layer and the service.  I am currently working through the sample app that comes with the DoFactory source code.  This question is based on the sample application, but in general.

There is a service layer (WCF) that exposes a set of service methods.  The service layer implements a single point of entry (the Façade pattern) through which all communication with the layers below must occur. The Façade is the entry point into the business layer and exposes a very simple, course-grained API.

Lets says I am trying to get a list of clients, then in the MVC controller it will call the repository's GetCustomers method, then this will call the service layers GetCustomers method.

I think I am a bit confused here.  Is this application architecture correct?  Shouldn't the controller call the service layer's method and then this call repository's method.  I always thought that the repository was always the last method called to get data?

Please can someone help clarify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your architecture is correct.

> I always thought that the repository was always the last method called to get data?

Yes, in your case the data comes from a WCF service but it could be anything: SQL database, XML file, ...

Comment: Thanks.  So you don't need a service that calls the repository which in turn gets it data from the WCF service?  Where would the logic be applied in this instance, in the WCF service layer?

Comment: @Brendan, no in this case you don't need an additional service. The business logic would be applied in the WCF layer.

Comment: Thanks! I was just confused regarding the service and a service layer. You have cleared it up for me :)